# datastore only matches root ancestor

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a structure such as this.

`User -> Language -> Property: value`

when I query:

`select * from Property where __key__ has ancestor(User, 'me')`

it returns my list of properties.

Yet when I query

`select * from Property where __key__ has ancestor(Language, 'en')`

Nothing is returned.

In the properties I can see that the google console UI does show the correct hierarchy. What is strange to me is that it seems to match the *root* parent rather than the intermediate links in the tree.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

With your second query, you are actually looking for a for a root entity with the key (Language, 'en').  To make the second query work, you want to do something like: `select * from Property where __key__ has ancestor KEY(User, 'me', Language, 'en')` .